# Сортировка массива Pascal

Tags: pascal

Как отсортировать одномерный массив так, чтобы положительные элементы чередовались с отрицательными без использования вспомогательных массивов, функций и процедур?

Comment: Идеи есть, и главная - не плодить халяву на форуме, Вы бы для начала ознакомились с правилами, какие вопросы здесь считаются приличными.

Answer (score 1):

Если гарантировано, что соотношение количества положительных и отрицательных элементов позволяет успешно решить задачу, то один из подходов может быть таким:

Запускаем два цикла while. Один шагает по чётным индексам, другой по нечётным. Первый останавливается, когда нашёл отрицательное число, второй - на положительном (для нечётной длины массива возможно, что подходит обратная ситуация)

Обменяем их местами и продолжим.

Comment: @Kromster Я хотел подчеркнуть, что важно соотношение +/- элементов (должно быть равно при чётной длине), правка этот акцент затеняла.

Comment: Вы правы, простите, посчитал это опечаткой не вчитавшись в предложение в целом. *"позволяет задачу успешно решить" все же лучше перекомпоновать в "позволяет успешно решить задачу".*